# Aliased an awk command successfully now won't use OFS

Tags: command-line, quoting, alias

So I was able to get a command finally with the ability to get and grep the information from a specific file I wanted and then I ran into a problem with alias:

```
find ./ -type f -name filename.ext  -exec grep 'information' {} + | sort | awk -v OFS='\n' '{print $5, $1, $2, $3 }'
```

From there I was able to figure out that I needed to change my alias after looking it up and I did it as such:

```
find ./ -type f -name filename.ext  -exec grep 'information' {} + | sort | awk -v OFS='\n' '{print \$5, \$1, \$2, \$3 }'
```

So now it prints but I still wanted to use the OFS but I am not sure the syntax to get the OFS to load. Thanks in advance!

```
 alias aliascommand="find ./ -type f -name filename.ext  -exec grep 'information' {} + | sort | awk -v \OFS='\t' '{print \$5 \$1 \$2 \$3 }'"
```

A variation of the above is what I put into my alias.

Comment: What's the alias?

Comment: edited this to show the alias.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the backslash before `OFS`, but I also can't see any problems with that, with or without the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
alias foo="...'{print $5 $1 $2 $3 }'"
```

The positional parameters will be expanded when the alias is set. They are within a double-quoted string, after all. You don't want that, so you had to escape them with backslashes. Alternatively, you could have put the whole alias text in single-quotes, but since you want to use single quotes in the alias, that gets rather difficult.

That `\n` should be fine within the double quotes, though.

In any case, you should probably use a function instead. That way you don't need to think about the extra level of quoting around the commands.

```
mycommand() {
    find ./ -type f -name filename.ext -exec grep 'information' {} + |
       sort |
       awk -v OFS='\n' '{print $5, $1, $2, $3 }'
}
```